# Understanding SQL Server Database name vs file location

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-design

I'm confused by all the different names the same database is given.  Take this code for example:

```
CREATE DATABASE DB_nameA  
ON   
( NAME = DB_nameB,  FILENAME = 'C:\myDatabases\DB_nameC.mdf')  
LOG ON  
( NAME = DB_log, FILENAME = 'C:\myDatabases\DB_log.ldf'     ) ;  
GO
```

What's the difference between DB_nameA, DB_nameB, and DB_nameC?  How does SQL Server keep track of which names are associated with each other?  E.g. Somehow when I write "DROP DATABASE DB_nameA", SQL knows to delete the "DB_nameC.mdf" file.

DB_nameA is how I'd refer to a database in SQL (e.g. DROP DATABASE DB_nameA).  And DB_nameC is the file name I'd see in Windows Explorer.  But when is DB_nameB ever used or seen again?

Comment: [CREATE DATABASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-sql-server-transact-sql)`database_name
Is the name of the new database; NAME logical_file_name Specifies the logical name for the file.; FILENAME { 'os_file_name' | 'filestream_path' }
Specifies the operating system (physical) file name`

Comment: Short answer: DB_nameA is the name of your database, DB_nameB is the logical name of the primary data file (used to refer to the file in SQL), DB_nameC is the physical file's name (e.g. what you'd search for on your computer/server if you wanted to find the database file).

Answer (score 2):

`CREATE DATABASE <logical db name>
ON
( NAME = <logical data filename>,  FILENAME = <physical data file path>)
LOG ON
( NAME = <logical log filename>, FILENAME = <physical log file path>);
GO`

Answer (score 0):

DB_nameA is your Database Name

For each database, MDF and LDF files are required.

MDF - Master Database File(Primary data file)
LDF - Log Database File(Transaction File)

So whenever creating a database,we have to specify "mdf" and "ldf" names along with the respective file path. All the data and transaction log files will be stored in respective files.

ex :

CREATE DATABASE DB_nameA
ON
( NAME = DB_nameA_Data,  FILENAME = 'C:\myDatabases\DB_nameA_Data.mdf')
LOG ON
( NAME = DB_nameA_log, FILENAME = 'C:\myDatabases\DB_nameA_log.ldf'     ) ;
GO